# Tableau automatically changing month format from names to numbers when published

Tags: date, formatting, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I have a workbook with several sheets and dashboards. I have the date as 3 letter month abbreviation (Jan, Feb, etc). When I publish to the server, it changes all the months to numbers 1-12. If I re-download the workbook, the months are back to alphabetical in Desktop but no matter what I try it reverts to numbers when I publish it, and no option to edit the date format in edit mode on the server.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens due to Automatic locale settings in Tableau

you need to change it to your country specifically

read more about locale settings here : https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/workbook_language.htm